# How to get old message reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

What I'm trying to do is to get `username` for users who reacts on that message. It's working good but when the bot restarts only new reactions work.
how to make it send all users reactions

```
client.on('ready', () => {
   client.guilds.get('guild_id').channels.get('chnl_id').fetchMessage('msg_id');
});
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    const { message} = reaction;
    if(message.channel.id == 'chnl_id'){
      if(reaction.emoji.name === "✅") {
    message.guild.fetchMember(user.id).then(member => {
      if(user.bot)  return;
    else {
         message.channel.send(reaction.users.map(u => u.username.toString()))
        }
    })
    }}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the message, then you can filter the reaction of that message by emojis:

```
const reaction = await message.reactions.cache.filter(r=> r.emoji.name === '✅').first().fetch();
```

Then you can fetch all reactions with that specific emoji:

```
await reaction.users.fetch();
```

Then you can filter from that if you want to (for example your own bot), with:

```
const filteredReactions = reaction.users.cache.filter(r=> !r.bot);
```

And don't forget to put these in an async function.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used discord.js v11, but as I have seen from some code snippets, you just need to remove the '.cache' parts to get a working v11 code.